# xslt with multiple templates

Tags: xml, xslt

How do you apply multiple templates in xslt ?  The first part of the xslt is used to remove namespaces and prefixes.  The second part is used to convert an attribute (Offset) to a new element.

**Sample XML input**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<S:Body>
  <ns3:getResponse xmlns="https://dataservices.ipt.com/scheduleRequest" xmlns:ns2="https://dataservices.ipt.com/ScheduleResult" xmlns:ns3="https://dataservices.ipt.com/Schedules" xmlns:ns4="https://dataservices.ipt.com/xsd/inf">
     <ns2:ScheduleResult as-of-date="2018-010-11T14:09:46.083Z">
        <ns2:Schedules>
           <ns2:ScheduleKeys>
              <ns2:ScheduleID>ABCD</ns2:ScheduleID>
              <ns2:SourceSystemName Offset="GMT6">Cloud_1</ns2:SourceSystemName>
           </ns2:ScheduleKeys>
        </ns2:Schedules>
     </ns2:ScheduleResult>
  </ns3:getResponse>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <Body>
      <getResponse>
         <ScheduleResult as-of-date="2018-010-11T14:09:46.083Z">
            <Schedules>
               <ScheduleKeys>
                  <ScheduleID>ABCD</ScheduleID>
                  <SourceSystemName>
                    <SystemName>Cloud_1</SystemName>
                    <Offset>GMT6</Offset>
                  </SourceSystemName>
               </ScheduleKeys>
            </Schedules>
         </ScheduleResult>
      </getResponse>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**attempted XSLT**

Note that when the first part of the xslt is run by itself, the namespaces and prefixes are removed as desired.  Also, when the second part of the XSLT is run by itself, the Attribute to new element is handled properly.  However, when combining the 2 parts of the XSLT together (as shown here) only the 2nd part works.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Remove all namespaces and prefixes -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Convert any elements with Offset                             -->
    <!-- From                                                         -->
    <!-- <SourceSystemName Offset="GMT6">Cloud_1</SourceSystemName>   -->
    <!-- To                                                           -->
    <!-- <SourceSystemName>                                           -->
    <!--     <SystemName>Cloud_1</SystemName>                         -->
    <!--     <Offset>GNT6</WeightUOM>                                 -->
    <!-- </SourceSystemName                                           -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@Offset]/text()" />

    <xsl:template match="@Offset">
        <SystemName>
            <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
        </SystemName>
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Generated output from XSLT**

Unfortunately, only the 2nd half of the XSLT is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:getResponse xmlns:ns3="https://dataservices.ipt.com/Schedules" xmlns="https://dataservices.ipt.com/scheduleRequest" xmlns:ns2="https://dataservices.ipt.com/ScheduleResult" xmlns:ns4="https://dataservices.ipt.com/xsd/inf">
         <ns2:ScheduleResult as-of-date="2018-010-11T14:09:46.083Z">
            <ns2:Schedules>
               <ns2:ScheduleKeys>
                  <ns2:ScheduleID>ABCD</ns2:ScheduleID>
                  <ns2:SourceSystemName>
                      <SystemName xmlns="">Cloud_1</SystemName>
                      <Offset xmlns="">GMT6</Offset>
                  </ns2:SourceSystemName>
               </ns2:ScheduleKeys>
            </ns2:Schedules>
         </ns2:ScheduleResult>
      </ns3:getResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then the rest should do (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRc), unless you have any processing instructions or comments you also want to be copied, for those you could add a template.